# what should i do so that i can remove name error

Tags: python

```
word_sentences = [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-25-919de5639f2e>", line 1, in <module>
    word_sentences = [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]

NameError: name 'sentences' is not defined
```

Comment: define sentences

Comment: ...before the list

Comment: How can i define the sentence.can u give me example

Comment: First of all, do you actually know at least the basics of python? it doesnt seem like you do, is this just a copy pasted code from somewhere else that you have no idea about what it is doing? Well in order to define it you can just use the assignment `=` operator, you have to try to learn and understand the code first before anything

Answer (score 0):

What does `sentences` look like? Please provide the complete code. However, here is a small code snippet assuming `sentences` is a list of lists.

```
from nltk.tokenize import  word_tokenize

sentences = [['hello, miss'],['this is a cat']]
for sentence in sentences:
    print(word_tokenize(sentence[0]))
```